# Setting a public endpoint for each server which is behind a load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, amazon-elb

Given that there are a load balancer(e.g. AWS ELB) and multiple server instances associated to the load balancer, can I set up a public endpoint (e.g. NAT forwarding) for each server instance as well? I need this for a mobile client reconnects to the same server after the IP address of the client is changed by Wifi to Cellular Network handover.

[image: Two endpoints for each server]

With stateless servers (e.g. Web servers) and memory cache (e.g. Redis), my question is needless, however, I am using stateful servers (e.g. Socket servers).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

In AWS, the public address is already exposed when I create an EC2 instance. Just adding a Security Group with adding port numbers to Inbound is the only necessity.